# How to always clear hlsearch on clicking enter?

Tags: vim, mapping

Right now I am using:

```
nnoremap <cr> :nohlsearch<cr><cr>k
```

But after I press `Enter` my cursor goes to beginning of line.

I have additional `<cr>k` because I want to use default `<Enter>` behaviour for example when I try to open file in Ack results quickview.

Comment: What do you mean by _disable cursor in the same position_?

Comment: I mean to stay in the same position as before I clicked ``<Enter>``

Comment: Why do you have the `<cr>k` then in the mapping? Do you actually understand what it does, or did you just blindly copy this from somewhere?

Comment: One thing I did was use `<leader><space>` to clear the hl, and it seems to work pretty good. I just do `,<spacebar>` and it clears it: https://github.com/Greduan/dotfiles/blob/118d0e541b4bc263472506c1388023b3f91ca97d/vim/vimrc.vim#L406-L407

Comment: Yep, but I used to have enter for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach is to locally override the new behavior in the quickfix window and the command-line window, where `<CR>` has special meaning:

```
:nnoremap <CR> :nohlsearch<CR>
:autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>
:autocmd CmdwinEnter * nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want Enter to keep the default behavior, then this mapping should take care of it.

```
nnoremap <CR> :nohlsearch<CR><CR>
```

It turns off search highlighting, moves the cursor down, and only applies to normal mode.

Comment: But I want to keep default Enter behaviour.

Comment: Updated my answer. I missed that part the first time. Sorry :(